# How to generate Azure AD token using OKTA token in ASP.NET

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, okta

I do have a problem while generating the Azure AD token from the OKTA token generated.

The flow is:

An angular application authenticates with OKTA (configured an application in OKTA as SPA) and gets both Access Token and ID Token as response. Now we would like to generate the Azure AD token (by registering an application in the Azure Tenant) and use it to protect all the REST APIs hosted in Azure.

I tried to search for the solution using Chat GPT and tried the suggested code. But seeing the error

**Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: 'AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - The key was not found., Please visit the Azure Portal, Graph Explorer or directly use MS Graph to see configured keys for app Id '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'.**

I am sure that I am missing some configuration either in OKTA side or Azure side. Can someone help with this if anyone came across the same scenario.

Please note that, I cannot change any authentication flow (need to use OKTA and Azure in the same manner).